# Tracking CPU usage after logical offline

Tags: linux, performance, x86, cpu, cpu-usage

I am interested in any possible way to track CPU usage, and list of processes/interrupts occurring on CPU core that has been logically offlined via:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/online
```

Is there a file or any object that still tracks processes/interrupts that occurred on such core since to most of measuring programs the core is invisible (for example top)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of taking a CPU offline is making sure it won't execute any processes or any IRQs (there'd be nothing to track).

Note that "offline" is part of hot-plug support and is intended as "ready to be unplugged from the computer", it's just that most real hardware doesn't support hot-plug CPUs.

Comment: I see. However, is that a hard guarantee or not? Reason why I'm trying to track the usage of offlined CPU is to make sure that scheduler doesn't unexpectedly acquire the offlined core. Also, what about kernel-level threads do they still get allocated on such core or not?

Comment: @Anton9988: I'd expect that the kernel puts the core in its lowest power state and does a `cli` (to disable all IRQs) and `hlt` (to wait for an IRQ that won't happen because they're disabled); resulting in the core (literally) being unable to execute a single instruction (until/unless it's brought back online by a special "AP CPU startup/reset" sequence).

Comment: @Anton9988: I should add that, while most real hardware doesn't support hot-plug CPUs, some do/did, and some virtual machines do. If scheduler could acquire the offline core then it'd be a major bug (but there's never a guarantee that there's no major bugs).

Comment: When you say doesn't support hot-plugging CPU, you mean physical hot-plug/turnoff?

Comment: @Anton9988: Yes.  Literally pull the processor package out of one of the motherboard's sockets (and optionally put in a new one) while the system is still running on CPU cores in other sockets.  (Obviously only makes sense with a multi-socket system, and of course only one that's electrically designed for this, as well as in terms of bootup.)

Comment: Exactly like hot-swapping a failed SATA drive in a RAID array; SATA power/data connectors have longer ground pins so that contacts first, making hot-swap safe.  For CPUs, only very big-iron / high-reliability & update systems would support this.  The amount of connections between a CPU package and other parts of the system is vastly higher than with SATA, and the latency requirements are generally much lower, so it's a harder design problem and very much not worth it unless you truly need it, unlike SATA.

Comment: Bad memory or CPU would probably corrupt something and need a reboot anyway, so systems with hot-swappable CPUs presumably have redundancy to detect errors before they corrupt global kernel data, if that's the motivation for taking CPUs offline.  (If it's just to *upgrade* memory connected to a socket, that could make sense, or replace bad RAM where ECC detects a bit that's consistently failing while the errors are still correctable.)